# How to install Firebug lite IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, firebug, ie-developer-tools

So we have reached that stage in a web dev project where we need to see how things look in IE.

Sigh.

So the fabulous Firebug is not available for IE. But a lite version is - as a bookmarklet, and is apparently compatible with IE6+. But how the how the hell do I add a bookmarklet to IE8?

I am unable to drag and drop to the Favourites bar (is this the same as bookmarks?). I can't add it through the Favourites add option as it contains "illegal" characters.

So how do I do this? All I want to do is inspect the DOM.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the debugger built into IE8? It's actually pretty good.

Comment: @Ferruccio, thanks I'll check it out. Does IE7 have a debugger too? That's the next port of call, so I'll still need Firebug lite if not.

Comment: IE7 you can use the developer toolbar  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535

Comment: I think it's new in IE8. But you can always run IE8 in compatibility mode. In theory it would work like IE7.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the developer toolbar in IE8. It never worked well for me. Firebug is updated regularly and allows you to edit settings quickly and intuitively. The built in toolbar is very different and kludgy and has never been updated. Did I mention it never worked well for me. It never did. I work on the front end A LOT.

Comment: The link for a visual step by step: http://youtu.be/vLJ2RaNZ22E

Answer (score 36):

this is how I did it (IE 8.0.7600.16385 on Win7):

- Go to some Firebug Lite page (http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).
- Click the "add to Favorites Bar"
  button on the Favorites Bar.
- This
  will give you a bookmark to
  http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite.
- click on the "Firebug Lite" link in Firebug Lite page (http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

  - properties poup will be open. Copy the URL within the popup
  - Right click on your new bookmark and choose Properties.
- Paste the URL into the URL box and close.
- If you hover over the new bookmark, it should show `javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E)...` etc instead of the link.

Comment: this also has the nice side effect of attaching the firebug faveicon to the bookmark

Comment: note that there is a bug with Firebug lite 1.4 on IE8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532909/firebug-lite-messagequeue-null

Comment: To question editor: you cannot simply paste the code for Firebug lite into an answer here due the license: https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/license.txt

Comment: If you have trouble getting the source from the firebug site, this question has the source with the required license included: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203640/ie8-developer-tools-javascript-minimized/6203716#6203716

Answer (score 2):

Please use this in your jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

and you are done.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. The website shows `firebug-lite.js`.