# IE8 Developer Tools Javascript Minimized

Tags: javascript, ie-developer-tools

When I open the IE8 Developer Tools (using F12), click on Scripts, and choose the project's .js file, the Javascript that is displayed is minified. This makes debugging almost impossible. In researching, I found a reference to a "configuration button" that appears would pretty-print the Javascript source. Unfortunately I cannot find that button in the IE8 Developer Tool tool-strip or menu. XP SP3 TIA Gus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately that is only available in IE9's developer tools, in the configuration menu: [image]

[MSDN article on Dev Tools in IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#prettyprintscript)

**Edit**:

One last option could be using FirebugLite, if infact IE8 is minifying the javascript for you, Firebug should not, you can get FirebugLite in IE by using it in a bookmarklet: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

basically what you have to do is create a bookmark in IE (of say the firebuglite website) then right click -> properties, and change the URL to be:

```
javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');
```

when you click the bookmark, firebug should popup in the bottom of the page

---

EDIT: Firebug (including Lite) [has a BSD license](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/license.txt).  Since the source code is reproduced in this answer, the following license should be included:

> Software License Agreement (BSD License)
>
> Copyright (c) 2009, Mozilla Foundation
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Redistribution and use of this software in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
>   are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> - Redistributions of source code must retain the above
>     copyright notice, this list of conditions and the
>     following disclaimer.
> - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
>     copyright notice, this list of conditions and the
>     following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other
>     materials provided with the distribution.
> - Neither the name of Mozilla Foundation nor the names of its
>     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
>     derived from this software without specific prior
>     written permission of Mozilla Foundation.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR
>   IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
>   CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
>   DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
>   DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER
>   IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT
>   OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

Comment: Is there anyway to pretty-print the Javascript that appears in the IE8 Developer Tools Javascript window?

Comment: @Gus - not that I know of, unfortunately. If you want to be able to read it (obviously wouldn't be able to debug) you could try using another service, such as: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home to 'pretty-print' the javascript...

Comment: The Javascript is already in "pretty-print format". It seems that IE8 is minifying it.

Comment: @Gus - you may be bound by IE, especially due to a specific bug, but I find reading/debugging javascript in FireFox/Chrome much easier